# Two approaches to git non-bare server synchronization with client pushed commits

Tags: git

Are the following two repository configurations equivalent to the point that I can stop thinking about the differences or is there some problem lingering that will bite me later? The reason I ask is that the docs contain the word "dangerous" in the relevant places.

I just had a look at two non-bare remote repositories (A,B) that have near identical .git folder content.

A has a .git/config with `receive.denyCurrentBranch = updateInstead` and no hooks.

B has a .git/config with `receive.denyCurrentBranch = ignore` and a hooks/post-receive with `git checkout -f`.

According to [the git documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#Documentation/git-config.txt-receivedenyCurrentBranch):

> If [denyCurrentBranch is] set to false or "ignore", [then] allow such pushes with no message.

That page also says:

> Another option is "updateInstead" which will update the working tree if pushing into the current branch.

Since "ignore" makes no mention of a checkout, I am left with the assumption that someone created the post-receive hook to keep the working copy synchronized with the git index. That way, when a commit is pushed, the changes are checked out.

On the surface, the behavior appears to be the same but I'd like to hear more.

Comment: Haven't tried but perhaps `updateInstead` is atomic where `ignore` + hook is not. E.g. not sure what happens if git can't sync the working tree after you pushed with `updateInstead`. Does it rollback and reset the commits? That certainly wouldn't be the case with the hook, because the hook happens as a side-effect of the push.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a number of subtle differences here, but the key to being able to ignore them, as it were, is to ask whether there is *any* chance that someone might, on the server, go into the work-tree of the non-bare repository and start messing around with it.

If there is no chance of this ever happening, either method will produce the same result, at least in most of the practical and useful cases.  As [plalx mentions in a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64672809/two-approaches-to-git-non-bare-server-synchronization-with-client-pushed-commits#comment114351850_64672809), there are some additional minor differences that might affect you:

- Multiple "simultaneous" push operations might go awry, because a post-receive hook runs asynchronously after dropping locks.  That is, if the `git checkout` you do in the post-receive starts at the *same time* as another `git push` starts, the second `git push` could start running a `git checkout` in another (separate) post-receive run *while* the first `git checkout` is still running.  In practice this just means that the *second* `git checkout` will see that the index is locked, and will fail (leaving the first checkout in place).

  Since the `updateInstead` hook runs while the ref update is locked, this can't happen for this particular update mode.
- If, e.g., the server's disk drive goes bad or becomes full, the checkout result might fail and the work-tree might be left in a bad state.  The exact bad state would differ.  This, however, is a nightmare scenario that usually involves a subsequent wipe-and-reinstall of the server anyway.

Overall this is an argument for using `updateInstead`: it's simpler, built in, and doesn't run any risk of "simultaneous" checkouts interfering with each other, which in turn results in the checkout failing.  (However, if a post-receive checkout *does* fail like this, that's easily worked around by re-doing the push.)

There are two or three other things to think about here:

- Will the bare repository have additional work-trees added?  The `updateInstead` hook does not account for this possibility.
- Is there only one particular branch that should be deployed?  The `updateInstead` hook handles this gracefully; to do this well in your post-receive hook, you need a smarter post-receive hook.  If there are more branches that should each be deployed differently, you will need a post-receive hook.

Last, this isn't right:

> I am left with the assumption that someone created the post-receive hook to keep the working copy synchronized with the git index.

The point of the post-receive hook is to do something after receiving a push.  That "something" can be *anything* that you can do with a repository.  One of the main motivations for this hook was the post-receive email generator, which delivers mail to a mailing list mentioning what commits were just pushed.  Two scripts for doing this are included in the Git distribution (the old `post-receive-email` and the new and improved `multimail/*`).

Separate from this, the working copy and Git's index are (normally—see next paragraph) automatically in sync with *each other* (because the index contains stat data for the work-tree, so that updates made *to* the work-tree invalidate the index stat data), as it were.  What goes wrong when the *current commit hash ID* changes is that the index content becomes out of sync with the *current commit hash ID* in ways that Git didn't expect.  That's why an update to the current branch is normally refused in a non-bare repository.

This second bit is just a terminology nit: it's not that the index and *work-tree* get decoupled by the push.  Instead, it is—sort of at least—that the index and the *repository* get decoupled.  There are cases where the index and work-tree *can* get decoupled though.  In particular, using `--git-work-tree` without regard to the fact that the index has to be coupled to one *particular* work-tree, so that you point the index at different work-trees without care, can do this.